# rows filled with NA values for multiple filters

Tags: r

When I try below code, Rows 251 to 2486 are filled with NA values.

Please tell me, What is wrong with this code?

```
> dim(email)
[1] 3921 21

> firstFilter = email[email$spam == 1,]
> dim(firstFilter)
[1] 367 21

> secondFilter = firstFilter[email$exclaim_mess > 0,] #**Unexpected output**
> dim(secondFilter)
[1] 2486 21
```

Package information,

```
install.packages("openintro")
```

Comment: What about `secondFilter = firstFilter[firstFilter$exclaim_mess > 0,]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
 firstFilter = email[email$spam == 1,]
 secondFilter = firstFilter[firstFilter$exclaim_mess > 0,]
```

Comment: How can I achieve the same result with, (email[email$spam == 1,])[email$exclaim_mess > 0,] ?

Comment: @SunnyShah This should be in most tutorials: `email[email$spam == 1 & email$exclaim_mess > 0,]`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are confused about the existence of `NA`s after filtering. Well, if they are `NA`s, then subsetting with `email$spam==1` will keep these rows. After all, since they are missing, how do you know they are not equal to one?

To avoid this behavior, try wrapping your condition into `which()`.

Example:

```
 # use mtcars data and introduce NAs
 mtcars[mtcars$mpg>23,] <- NA
 dim(mtcars)
 > [1] 32 11
 dim(mtcars[mtcars$mpg<23,])
 > [1] 32 11
 dim(mtcars[which(mtcars$mpg<23),])
 > [1] 25 11
```